# SQL query to Rails query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4

My problem is this

i write query in sql like so:

```
SELECT sum(smsqs.count_sms) as nb_sms_sent,  count(smsq_receiveds.id) as nb_sms_received
FROM smsqs join smsq_receiveds on smsqs.id = smsq_receiveds.smsq_id
where smsq_receiveds.campaign = '436'
```

It work's very well.

In rails i have something like so:

```
SmsqReceived.joins(:smsq).select('sum(smsqs.count_sms) as nb_sms_sent,  count(smsq_receiveds.id) as nb_sms_received').where(:smsq_receiveds=> {:campaign => '436'})
```

But i don't have result

Result is something like:

```
  SmsqReceived Load (0.2ms)  SELECT sum(smsqs.count_sms) as nb_sms_sent,  count(smsq_receiveds.id) as nb_sms_received FROM `smsq_receiveds` INNER JOIN `smsqs` ON `smsqs`.`id` = `smsq_receiveds`.`smsq_id` WHERE `smsq_receiveds`.`campaign` = 436
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<SmsqReceived id: nil>]>
```

I execute this query:

```
SELECT sum(smsqs.count_sms) as nb_sms_sent,  count(smsq_receiveds.id) as nb_sms_received FROM `smsq_receiveds` INNER JOIN `smsqs` ON `smsqs`.`id` = `smsq_receiveds`.`smsq_id` WHERE `smsq_receiveds`.`campaign` = 436
```

On script sql, it work's well.

What's wrong with rails? Why my result is nil with rails?

Answer (score 0):

Rails is behaving as expected. The SmsqReceived Relation displays `id: nil` because the query did not select the id column.

```
SmsqReceived Load (0.2ms)  SELECT sum(smsqs.count_sms) as nb_sms_sent,  count(smsq_receiveds.id) as nb_sms_received FROM `smsq_receiveds` INNER JOIN `smsqs` ON `smsqs`.`id` = `smsq_receiveds`.`smsq_id` WHERE `smsq_receiveds`.`campaign` = 436
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<SmsqReceived id: nil>]>
```

You can access the count aggregates by their alias:

```
records = SmsqReceived.joins(:smsq).select('sum(smsqs.count_sms) as nb_sms_sent,  count(smsq_receiveds.id) as nb_sms_received').where(:smsq_receiveds=> {:campaign => '436'})
records.first.nb_sms_sent
records.first.nb_sms_received
```

If you want all the SmsqReceived attributes as well, include them in the select:

```
SmsqReceived.joins(:smsq).select('sms_receiveds.*, sum(smsqs.count_sms) as nb_sms_sent,  count(smsq_receiveds.id) as nb_sms_received').where(:smsq_receiveds=> {:campaign => '436'})
```